# Displaying Bing Maps WMS in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, wms

I am trying to display my bing map raster tiles in QGIS. I am using an HTML file like this, except with my own raster tiles, as described in [WMS Tile Layer Example](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/layers/wms-tile-layer-example).

My own raster tiles don't have a projection, they have quad keys.

Is there a way to add this to QGIS with Python?

I am guessing it is something to do with this, but I cannot quite figure it out. Got through some documentation [PyQGIS Cookbook | Raster Layers](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html#raster-layers) but with not much success.

My data is currently stored on S3, I have tried this:

```py
from osgeo import gdal

xml = """<GDAL_WMS>
    <Service name="VirtualEarth">
           <ServerUrl>
                  https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/key/t_${quadkey}.png
           </ServerUrl>
    </Service>
    <MaxConnections>4</MaxConnections>
    <Cache/>
</GDAL_WMS>"""

vfn = "/vsimem/bing.xml"
gdal.FileFromMemBuffer(vfn, xml)
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer(vfn, "sm")
rasterLyr.isValid()
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([rasterLyr])
```

Comment: Bing tiles are not a WMS and so won't load using the WMS driver

Comment: Do you know if there is another way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working with XYZ tiles.

I just put it in like this, https://s3.amazonaws.com/bucketname/key/b_{q}.png and it worked